# Sustainsys.Saml2 SLO Logout RequestDenied status error

Tags: saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I need help in implementing Single Logout.I'm able to implement SSO service successfully.But SLO service is not working.
I got RequestDenied status code after performing logout on my OWIN based asp.net MVC application.

```
<saml2p:LogoutRequest
Destination="https://sap-client.accounts.ondemand.com/saml2/idp/slo/sap-client.accounts.ondemand.com"
ID="idb2d655f7174f465696a433c75a717b46" IssueInstant="2019-08-03T02:16:03Z" Version="2.0"
xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<saml2:Issuer>https://sp.domain.com/Saml2</saml2:Issuer>
<saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">xxx@xxx.com</saml2:NameID>
<saml2p:SessionIndex>S-SP-6aff8686-a642-4381-8ab3-0f18c6815ffe</saml2p:SessionIndex>
```

```
<LogoutResponse Destination="https://sp.domain.com/Saml2/Logout" ID="S0e6a2f99-2517-4326-a8ce-2ede2dfe1bfa" InResponseTo="idb2d655f7174f465696a433c75a717b46" IssueInstant="2019-08-03T02:16:04.933Z" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ns2:Issuer>sap-client.accounts.ondemand.com</ns2:Issuer>
<Status>
    <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester">
        <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:RequestDenied" />
    </StatusCode>
    <StatusMessage>Identity Provider could not process the logout message received.</StatusMessage>
</Status>
```

Here is Owin log

Sustainsys.Saml2.Owin.Saml2AuthenticationMiddleware Error: 0 : Error in Saml2 for /Saml2/Logout
Sustainsys.Saml2.Exceptions.UnsuccessfulSamlOperationException: Idp returned status "Requester", indicating that the single logout failed. The local session has been successfully terminated.
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.LogoutCommand.HandleResponse(UnbindResult unbindResult, StoredRequestState storedRequestState, IOptions options, Uri returnUrl)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.LogoutCommand.Run(HttpRequestData request, String returnPath, IOptions options)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.Owin.Saml2AuthenticationHandler.d__4.MoveNext()
    ProcessId=14888
    DateTime=2019-08-04T06:16:22.3060366Z

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Idp returns an error. You should check the logs on the Idp to get more information on why.
It might also be worth using SAML dev tools for Chrome to check the actual messages, there might be more status codes embedded in the response.

One reason that this might occur is if you have a long lived session in your application that extends beyond the life time of the Idp session. With owin based applications where the external login session is typically swapped to an application login session this might happen - the session life time limit is lost in the swap done in ExternalLoginCallback.